# Error with undefined method CI_Loader::plugin()

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I received the following error:

> Call to undefined method CI_Loader::plugin() in C:\wamp\www\Code\application\libraries\DX_Auth.php on line 1233

on this code:

```
function captcha()
 {

    $this->ci->load->helper('url');


    $this->ci->load->plugin('dx_captcha');


    $captcha_dir = trim($this->ci->config->item('DX_captcha_path'), './');
```

Comment: Be a **lot** more specific! People can't help you if you only post the code with no description.

Comment: @Pheel +1 emphasis on  "a lot".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have moved any array values in application/config/autoload.php from $autoload[‘plugins’] to $autoload[‘helpers’] or you will notice stuff break.

This is the [reference](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0)

Comment: how create $autoload['plugins']

Answer (score 1):

Which version of CI are you using? Plugins has been removed since the 2.x and replaced with helper.
Try to use [reCaptcha](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) instead, it has a good library.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load a plugin and plugins are not supported, if I remember it right since CI version 2. If that's the case (which seems to be) you need to convert your plugins into helpers.

Comment: how can i convert plugin into helpers

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html - step 3 briefly describes how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use an old version of DX_Auth on new version of CodeIgniter. Current version of DX_Auth is compatible with CI 2.x and is available on [github](https://github.com/eyoosuf/DX-Auth).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is that you just put this code in your `loader.php`. The  plugin its works. Go to `System->Core->Loader.php`.

```
      /**
      * Load Plugin
       *
      * This function loads the specified plugin.
       *
     * @access      public
       * @param       array
      * @return      void
       */
     function plugin($plugins = array())
     {
              if ( ! is_array($plugins))
              {
                      $plugins = array($plugins);
             }

             foreach ($plugins as $plugin)
             {       
                      $plugin = strtolower(str_replace(EXT, '', str_replace('_pi', '', $plugin)).'_pi');              

                     if (isset($this->_ci_plugins[$plugin]))
                     {
                             continue;
                     }

                      if (file_exists(APPPATH.'plugins/'.$plugin.EXT))
                      {
                              include_once(APPPATH.'plugins/'.$plugin.EXT);   
                      }
                      else
                      {
                              if (file_exists(BASEPATH.'plugins/'.$plugin.EXT))
                              {
                                      include_once(BASEPATH.'plugins/'.$plugin.EXT);  
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                      show_error('Unable to load the requested file: plugins/'.$plugin.EXT);
                              }
                      }

                      $this->_ci_plugins[$plugin] = TRUE;
                      log_message('debug', 'Plugin loaded: '.$plugin);
              }               
      }

      // --------------------------------------------------------------------

      /**
       * Load Plugins
       *
       * This is simply an alias to the above function in case the
       * user has written the plural form of this function.
       *
       * @access      public
       * @param       array
       * @return      void
       */
      function plugins($plugins = array())
      {
              $this->plugin($plugins);
      }
```